# A Milnor Differential Topology Excercise

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

If $m<p$, show that every map $f:M^m\longrightarrow\ S^p$ is homotopic to a constant, where $M^m$ is smooth manifold of dimension $m$.

I tried to show that $M^m$ is contractible or convex, but I couldn't. Any Idea would be helpful.

Comment: Hint: If $M$ is not onto, one can use stereographic projection to make a contraction. If $f$ is $C^1$ , by $m<p$, $f$ is not onto (How?). What happens when $f$ is not $C^1$?

Comment: @John in the first sentence you mean "$f$ is onto"? I can't see how using stereographic projection can make a contraction.

Comment: Though it's equivalent to the stereographic projection approach, the following might be easier to visualize: Given a point $p$ on the sphere that isn't in the range of $f$, you can deform $f$ toward the antipode of $p$ by sliding everything along great circles away from $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on John's hint.

If $f$ is not onto then there is a $x_0\in S^n\setminus f(M)$, so $f$ is actually a map from $M$ into $S^n\setminus\{x_0\}$. Using that $S^n\setminus\{x_0\}\equiv \mathbb R^n$ (here we are using stereographic projection) then $f$ is essentially a map from $M$ into $\mathbb R^n$ since $\mathbb R^n$ is contractible $f$ is homotopic to a constant.

Comment: Got it! Thank you azarel.